# preg_replace multiple words case insensitive

Tags: php, regex

I need to use preg_replace to find 2+ case-insensitive specific words and replace all instances with the same string:

```
Find: AND, and, WITH, with

Replace: <span="blah">and</span>
```

I can use str_ireplace for a single word but need to handle both "and" and "with", and moving forward possibly more.

Answer (score 2):

use the modifier `i` for ignore case :

```
"/(and|with)/i"
```

and replace with :

```
/<span="blah">$1<\/span>/
```

Comment: Actually, this now does a replace for words like "Udland" and "Witherspoon", so I need to including a single space before and after each word ... so " and " and " with " ... in order to only match the actual words.

Comment: @rdpcoder sorry I didn't get what you mean? If you want to add space you can just add it before and after group number `/<span="blah"> $1 <\/span>/`

Comment: I want to replace any instances of " and " , " AND ", " with " and " WITH ", with:
    " <span class='myclass'>and</span> "

Note there is a single space at beginning of the word and end of the word so as to NOT match on words 'containing' those words, such as "Ireland" and "Witherspoon" ..